# Filtering the records between time of 10:00-16:59?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have one Time column where i need to filter out the records between given two time intervals.
What % of customers purchased between time of 10:00-16:59?

I tried few time functions in python, but nothing worked.

```
from datetime import datetime
s1 = '10:00'
s2 = '16:59' # for example
FMT = '%H:%M'
filt=df[(df['Gender']=='Female')&datetime(s1-s2)]
```

[image]

Comment: Is possible see data sample?

Comment: @jezrael can u see the data?

Comment: Sure, I only need know what is `Time` - if separate column, if part of datetimes or part of DatetimeIndex

Comment: date and time are two separate columns not related to each other.

Comment: Super, my solution working well?

Comment: TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: Added solution to answer.

Comment: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: Sorry, added `()` after `.time`

Comment: It works, May i know any better sites to know more about date time functions.

Comment: You can check functions for `Timestamp` - [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/arrays.html) - in my answer is used https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.time.html

Answer (score 1):

Convert column and strings to datetimes and filter in [`DataFrame.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between.html):

```
s1 = '10:00'
s2 = '16:59'
times = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df[(df['Gender']=='Female') & times.between(pd.to_datetime(s1), pd.to_datetime(s2))]
```

If there are `time`s in column:

```
s1 = '10:00'
s2 = '16:59'

t1 = pd.to_datetime(s1).time()
t2 = pd.to_datetime(s2).time()
df[(df['Gender']=='Female') & df['Time'].between(t1, t2)]
```